# "does not name a type" error when using namespaces in c++

Tags: c++, definition, statements

In the below code writing the statement `A::x=5` is giving the error:

> 'x' in namespace 'A' does not name a type

Can't we assign a value globally for `x` variable?

```
#include <iostream>

int x = 10;  

namespace A
{
    int x = 20; 
}

A::x=5;

int main()
{
    int x = 30; 
    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "A::x = " << A::x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "::x = " << ::x << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with namespaces. The following (at global scope) would have the same problem `int x = 20; x = 5;`

Answer (score 10):

> Can't we assign a value globally for `x` variable?

You can. But you must put the assignment statement into a function. e.g.

```
int main()
{
    A::x=5;
    int x = 30; 
    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "A::x = " << A::x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "::x = " << ::x << std::endl;
}
```

Note that `A::x=5;` is a [statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements), but not [definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) (with initializer) like `int x = 20;`, they're different things.

Comment: Or just set it to 5 instead of 20 when first defining it.